# How to combine/concat two jdbc sink connector Transforms?

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

In my Avro schema for a topic, there are two String fields, `field1` and `field2`. Is it currently possible to use built-in Transforms on a JDBC Sink Connector to combine these two Avro fields into a single database column (via concat, or bonus points for a concat with separator e.g. `.` or `:`) ? I'm familiar with some basic transforms, for example:

```
transforms=myTransform
transforms.myTransform.type:org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.InsertField$Value
transforms.myTransform.static.field:field2
transforms.myTransform.topic.value:field2
```

I'm essentially trying to do two of these `topic.value` lookups and then concat them into a single downstream db column.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't a Single Message Transform that I'm aware of that will do this.

You could write your own, or you could use ksqlDB to achieve the same:

```
CREATE STREAM mysource WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='source_topic', VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO');

CREATE STREAM concated WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='target_topic' 
  AS SELECT field1 + '.' + field2 AS concat_field, * 
     FROM mysource
```

From there you stream `target_topic` with the JDBC Sink connector (which, FWIW, you can do from within ksqlDB if you want, using `CREATE SINK CONNECTOR`)